# Daniel Ginidi ios-Charts Label Displayed - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I am still just learning Swift and was wondering if there is a way to display the label for a slice of a pie chart only if it is clicked? I will likely have 5+ slices in the chart, so I think it would be too crowded if the labels were displayed all the time.

Comment: Which chart you are using LineChart or Bar chart ?

Comment: I'm trying to use a Pie Chart

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can react to a click on a slice:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.pieChart.delegate = self;
    }

    func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {        
        print("entry \(entry)")
    }
}
```

But the chartValueSelected method does not help much to solve your problem.
You can set the variable isDrawLabelsEnabled to false or true, but that will hide/show all the labels. There is no way to just show one label at a time without changing the library.
So what you want to achieve is basically not possible without digging into the library it self and add the feature you want to the library.

Comment: Can the Marker View be used to make a custom pop-up if the slice is selected?